# How to cancel multiple networking requests using Moya

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire, moya

I am currently using [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) to structure my networking calls. Per their [docs](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/docs/Examples/Basic.md), I have configured it as the following:

```
enum SomeAPIService {
    case endPoint1(with: Object)
    case endPoint2(duration: Int)
}
```

When calling an endpoint (in this case, `endPoint1`), I do the following:

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<SomeAPIService>()
provider.request(.endPoint1(object: object)) { (result) in
switch result {
    case let .success(moyaResponse):
        finished(Result.success(value: moyaResponse.value))
    case let .failure(error):
        let backendError = BackendError(localizedTitle: "", localizedDescription: "Some error", code: moyaResponse.statusCode)
        finished(Result.failure(error: backendError))
    }
})
```

My goal is, upon the user performing an action, **cancel all the networking requests** that's happening.

Accordingly, Moya does allow one to cancel requests from the discussion [here](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/1023). From the most upvoted comment, someone mentioned `let request_1 = MoyaRequestXXXXX` and then `ruest_1.cancel()`

My problem is:

1. How would I keep pointer to the requests?
2. `provider` doesn't have a `cancel()` function - so how should I be calling it?

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Per the helpful suggestion about using `[Cancellable]`, I did the following:

(1) In my app's singleton instance called `Operator`, I added `var requests = [Cancellable]()`
(2) Every API call is added to the `requests` array as a Cancellable, like so:

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<SomeAPIService>()
Operator.shared.requests.append(provider as! Cancellable) //causing error
provider.request(.endPoint1(object: object)) { (result) in
//rest of the block omitted
```

I think I am not getting the syntax correct, and am adding the provider and not the request. However, since the request is itself a block, where would be the place to add the request?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `request` method returns a [`Cancellable`](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/Sources/Moya/Cancellable.swift). From the documentation we can read:

> The request() method returns a Cancellable, which has only one public function, cancel(), which you can use to cancel the request.

So according to this, I made a simple test and call:

```
var requests: [Cancellable] = []
@objc func doRequests() {
    for i in 1...20 {
        let request = provider.request(MyApi.someMethod) {
            result in
            print(result)
        }
        requests.append(request)
    }
    requests.forEach { cancellable in cancellable.cancel() } // here I go through the array and cancell each request.
    requests.removeAll()
}
```

I set up a proxy using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and it seems to be working as expected. No request was sent - each request was cancelled.

So, the answer to your questions is:

1. You can keep it in `[Cancellable]` array.
2. Go through the array and cancel each request that you want to cancel.

**EDIT**

The main problem is that you adding the provider to the array and you try to map `provider` as `Cancellable`, so that cause the error. 
You should add reqest to the array. Below you can see the implementation.

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<SomeAPIService>()
let request = provider.request(.endPoint1(object: object)) { // block body }
Operator.shared.requests.append(request)
//Then you can cancell your all requests.
```

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I added more in the question body as a response - it has to do with syntax in adding the requests. The main issue is the block syntax - the requests are blocks, and I don't know where it is appropriate to add the request in my `[Cancellable]` array.

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would just cancel the current provider session + tasks:

```
provider.manager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

Comment: I had a problem here, whereby if you want to make further requests afterwards after cancellation - on any other view controller, swift throws an error about previously invalidated requests.

Comment: @RowanGontier this is a bit unspecific... alamofire is killing your session with `invalidateAndCancel()` for you so that you should not have any problems, like you describe. you should take a look at threading and dont handle network stuff in your viewControllers btw.

Comment: One difference for me, might be that I was using provider.rx, instead of provider.request.